# Embedding a Dynamic Map into Php

Tags: php, html, dictionary, embed, minecraft

my name is Chris and this is my first help question.

I am having some issues trying to figure out how to embed a Minecraft Server Dynamic Map into my PHP.

The map is 209.105.236.244:8123

The code in which I am trying to embed it is

```
<div class="span6">
<?php if( protectThis("1, 2") ) : ?>
    <h1 class="page-header"><?php _e('You have the ability to view this map'); ?></h1>
    <p><?php _e('You will only be able to see this content if you have a <span class="label label-info">special</span> user level. ')?></p>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning"><?php _e(' ***Dynamic Map Here***'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I am just not able to figure out how to make the map display here instead of them just going to the url. :3

If anyone can provide me with a solution or even a jumping off point on how to go about this, that would be simply amazing! Please and thank you :)

Comment: your best bet would be to put it in an iframe `<iframe src='http://209.105.236.244:8123'></iframe>` . You will have to tweek the style for the iframe to get it sized and positioned where you want.

Comment: @Orangepill iframe worked perfectly after some configuring with the size like you said, Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you intend to call javascript based on the page source at 209.105.236.244:8123

You could forgo the echo `<?php _e(' ***Dynamic Map Here***'); ?>` and include your map related scripts here just as you did with your other html tags. It should still fall within your "else" condition so that these scripts are only called if your requirements are met.

In this case, any time protectThis("1, 2") is not true, the map should be displayed.

```
<?php if( protectThis("1, 2") ) : ?>
<h1 class="page-header"><?php _e('You have the ability to view this map'); ?></h1>
<p><?php _e('You will only be able to see this content if you have a <span class="label label-info">special</span> user level. ')?></p>
<?php else : ?>
<div class="alert alert-warning">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.json.js"></script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```